# React Ref undefined when useEffect hook fires

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have written a component and I want the Username field to focus when the component loads. In the `useEffect` I am having to use `setTimeout` otherwise I get an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')" as the ref isn't loaded by the time the `useEffect` hook fires.

Anyone know why this is happening?

```
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {Modal, Button, TextInput, Label} from 'flowbite-react';
import {Head, useForm} from '@inertiajs/react';

export default function Register() {
    const {data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset} = useForm({
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const usernameInputRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout((() =>{
            usernameInputRef.current.focus()
        }), 100)



        return () => {
            reset('password');
        };
    }, []);



    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        post(route('register'));
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Head title="Register Now"/>
            <Modal show="true">
                <form className="overflow-scroll" onSubmit={submit}>
                    <Modal.Header>Sign Up</Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>

                        <div>
                            <Label htmlFor="username" value="Username"/>

                            <TextInput
                                id="username"
                                name="username"
                                value={data.username}
                                className="mt-1 block w-full"
                                autoComplete="username"
                                onChange={(e) => setData('username', e.target.value)}
                                required
                                color={errors.username ? "failure" : ""}
                                helperText={
                                    <>
                                        <span className="font-medium">{errors.username}</span>
                                    </>
                                }
                                ref={usernameInputRef}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="mt-4">
                            <Label htmlFor="email" value="Email"/>

                            <TextInput
                                id="email"
                                type="text"
                                name="email"
                                value={data.email}
                                className="mt-1 block w-full"
                                autoComplete="username"
                                onChange={(e) => setData('email', e.target.value)}
                                required
                                color={errors.email ? "failure" : ""}
                                helperText={
                                    <>
                                        <span className="font-medium">{errors.email}</span>
                                    </>
                                }
                            />

                        </div>

                        <div className="mt-4">
                            <Label htmlFor="password" value="Password"/>

                            <TextInput
                                id="password"
                                type="password"
                                name="password"
                                value={data.password}
                                className="mt-1 block w-full"
                                autoComplete="new-password"
                                onChange={(e) => setData('password', e.target.value)}
                                required
                                color={errors.password ? "failure" : ""}
                                helperText={
                                    <>
                                        <span className="font-medium">{errors.password}</span>
                                    </>
                                }
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <div className="flex items-center justify-end  w-full">
                            <Button type="submit" className="w-full text-center" disabled={processing}>Register</Button>
                        </div>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </form>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: The `TextInput` has an `autoFocus` prop, which would save you the need for ref and `useEffect`.

Comment: As @OriDrori says you can simply autofocus the element when it loads into the DOM with the `autoFocus` prop. It is worth noting that you should first check if `usernameInputRef.current` has a value, which it won't do until the element has mounted, [here's an example](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-ref-returns-undefined-or-null#access-the-current-property-of-the-ref-in-an-event-handler) when the ref.current "gets a value"

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check usernameInputRef.current
try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (usernameInputRef.current) {
          usernameInputRef.current.focus();
        }
      }, 100);
      return () => {
        reset('password');
      };
    }, []);
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (usernameInputRef.current) {
          usernameInputRef.current.focus();
        }
      }, 100);
    
      return () => {
        reset('password');
      };
    }, [usernameInputRef]);
```